# Alternate method for RandomAccessFileOrArray(byte[])

Tags: java, itext

Can anyone please tell me what the alternate method is for `RandomAccessFileOrArray(byte[])` for iText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From java doc located at http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/RandomAccessFileOrArray.html

```
RandomAccessFileOrArray(byte[] arrayIn)
          Deprecated. use RandomAccessSourceFactory.createSource(byte[]) and RandomAccessFileOrArray(RandomAccessSource) instead
```

Comment: Worked just great ! Thank you.